# How to save config change on chntpw and quit Terminal?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, gnome-terminal, password-recovery

So, I used the chntpw to clear my Windows 8 Admin password, but it does not apply the change when I restart the computer.

I read in some places that the config needs to be saved before closing the Terminal, but none of the commands that I've found (such as Ctrl+O; Esc; :wq) works!

I don't know what to do.... can someone save me?.... *_*

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem was not related with saving the changes.

The latest version of chntpw has a bug, the program appears to work exactly as expected, and doesn't display any errors, and acts like it's done everything properly when blanking or changing a password. However, when Windows is loaded, no change has been made - the password has not been blanked or changed. There is nothing you can do about it in this version.

The solution is to use the chntpw version 0.99.5-0+nmu1, that can be download here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chntpw/0.99.5-0+nmu1/+build/634460

It worked just fine for me, no more password on Windows 8! =D

=)

Answer (score 0):

what method are you using to clear the password? the best way would be to follow my guide.

goto shell

Cd media/sda?/Windows/System32/

type "find cmd.exe" press enter
type "find osk.exe" press enter
type "cp cmd.exe osk.exe" press enter
reboot

in windows click the bottom left icon then on screen keyboard then the cmd windows pops up.

type net user

type net user reboot.pro *
put password in or leave blank
login

remember to change your drive path to the drive you want to use

hope this helped